# I want the php results to be displayed on the same page instead of a completely new page

Tags: php, html, mysql, search

I'm trying to search by name and display the results on the same page.
My php code and the html code are in 2 separate files. Given below is my search.php code.

```
<?php
include_once '../connection.php';
include_once '../session.php';
$output = '';
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
        $searchquery=$_POST['search'];
        
                            


$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM details where customername LIKE '%$searchquery'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count == 0) {
    $output = 'There was no search result!';
}else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $ID = $row['id'];
        $Name= $row['customername'];
        $Type = $row['type'];
        $Phone = $row['phoneno'];
        $Email = $row['email'];
        
        $output .= '<div>' .$Name.' '.$Type.' '.$Phone.' '.$Email.'<div>';
    }
}
    

    }
?>


<?php print("$output");?>
```

Given below is the html code for my form.

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST" >
            <center><input type="text"  name="search" placeholder="Search by name" >
            <input type="submit"  value="Search"></center>
            <br>
            <table id="myTable">
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Telephone Number</th>
                <th>Email</th>
               
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
              </tr>
                <?php
                    $i=0;
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["customername"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["type"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["phoneno"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
```

When I search, the results are displayed on a completely new page. But  I want the results to be displayed on the same page with all the existing page layout, headers and footers.
How can I achieve this?
Thank in Advance!

Comment: 1- for layout it's ok to see the new page but include the layout with `include('header.php")`
2- use `ajax` to see the result on the same page if you know what is `ajax`

Comment: Create `function` and return the value from your function. Finally use the `function` in your html page within the `php`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your first file name is index.php.
Then need to call this file on form action & little bit refactor a file. Now it have $output array which is empty. If it contains search parameter, it will fill data to $output array and then on html part it checks if $output array has data to display it.

```php
<?php
include_once '../connection.php';
include_once '../session.php';
$output = array();
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchquery=$_POST['search'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM details where customername LIKE '%$searchquery'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="POST" >
            <center><input type="text"  name="search" placeholder="Search by name" >
            <input type="submit"  value="Search"></center>
            <br>
            <?php if(count($output) > 0): ?>
            <table id="myTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Telephone Number</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach($output as $row): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["customername"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["type"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["phoneno"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```